# How many books did Gilderoy Lockhart write?

Tags: harry-potter

We know Gilderoy Lockhart wrote the multi-volume "Magical Me."
But there are other books as well that he wrote, including one about pests.

What is the total number of books that Gilderoy Lockhart wrote, counting each book of Magical Me as a unique title?

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Books_by_Gilderoy_Lockhart

Comment: Isn't Magical Me just a single book, not a series?

Comment: I think all the "Break With A Banshee" etc books are part of Magical Me. Magical Me being the name for the series. @AnthonyGrist

Comment: @TheAsh That wasn't the impression I got, and it doesn't match what the wiki page Valorum linked to says either. Magical Me was the name of his autobiography, but seems to be separate from the others, not a collective name for them.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194953/is-magical-me-a-distinct-work-or-is-it-just-the-title-for-gilderoy-lockharts/194954#194954

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The Wiki is ALWAYS wrong.

Comment: @TheAsh the wiki isnt always wrong... If it provides references/quotes from the book then it can be reliable

Comment: Any book from him is one too many.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There appear to be nine books; however, both Fred Weasley and Lockhart himself describe the seven books on the Hogwarts list as the complete set

In the beginning of *Chamber of Secrets* Harry's booklist contains the following titles by Gilderoy Lockheart:

1. *Break with a Banshee*
2. *Gadding with Ghouls*
3. *Holidays with Hags*
4. *Travels with Trolls*
5. *Voyages with Vampires*
6. *Wanderings with Werewolves*
7. *Year with the Yeti*

Fred promptly says (my emphasis):

> "You've been told to get **all Lockhart's books**, too!"

This would imply that the complete set of Lockhart's books is seven in number.

When they are degnoming the garden Mrs. Weasley reads from *Gilderoy Lockhart's Guide to Household Pests* so that brings us up to eight books altogether.

When they meet Lockhart in Flourish and Blotts he is signing copies of *Magical Me*, which would bring us up to nine books.

Lockhart gives Harry a complete set of his books:

> The crowd cheered and clapped and Harry found himself being presented
>   with the entire works of Gilderoy Lockhart.

Harry promptly gives these books to Ginny:

> "You have these." Harry mumbled to her, tipping the books into the
>   cauldron. "I'll buy my own –"

This implies that there wouldn't be too many other books besides for the seven that were required for school, because otherwise there would be no need to give them to Ginny, nor to buy others for himself.

Lockhart himself, in the first Defense Against the Dark arts class appears to describe the books on the Hogwarts list as the complete set:

> "I see you've all bought a complete set of my books – well done."

Comment: Part of the confusion is that when they made the books into films, they made the last couple two-parters to squeeze more money out of the franchise...<g>

Answer (score 6):

## There may be twelve - he Obliviated twelve people for his books.

In the Pottermore writing by JKR on Gilderoy Lockhart, it’s stated that he modified the memory of a dozen wizards and witches so he could take credit for what they did, and that he came back with a new book ready for publication after each ‘adventure’ on what he supposedly did.

> The truth was that Lockhart had found his true calling at last. He had never been a bad wizard, only a lazy one, and he had decided to hone his talents in one direction: Memory Charms. By perfecting this tricky spell, he had succeeded in modifying the recollections of a dozen highly accomplished and courageous witches and wizards, allowing him to take credit for their daring exploits, returning to Britain at the end of each ‘adventure’ with a new book ready for publication which retold ‘his’ feats of bravery with a wealth of invented detail. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Gilderoy Lockhart (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/gilderoy-lockhart)*</sup></sub>

That suggests, presuming each individual wizard’s exploits were turned into a new book (which seems likely enough), that he’d have written at least twelve books in all.

## Lockhart wrote at least nine books that were named in total.

In total, there are at least nine books that Lockhart wrote. Lockhart wrote a guide to exterminating household pests, which Mrs. Weasley has in her house.

> “Harry looked at the cover of Mrs Weasley’s book. Written across it in fancy gold letters were the words: Gilderoy Lockhart’s Guide to Household Pests.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 3 (The Burrow)*</sup></sub>

There were seven of Lockhart’s books on the Hogwarts required book list as necessary textbooks for Defense Against the Dark Arts classes. The book list doesn’t require Hogwarts students to buy all of Lockhart’s books, as there are at least two of his books that we know of that are not on it.

> “*Break with a Banshee* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> *Gadding with Ghouls* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> *Holidays with Hags* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> *Travels with Trolls* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> *Voyages with Vampires* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> *Wanderings with Werewolves* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> *Year with the Yeti* by Gilderoy Lockhart” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 4 (At Flourish and Blotts)*</sup></sub>

He also wrote his autobiography, Magical Me, which he was selling in Flourish and Blotts.

> “GILDEROY LOCKHART
>
> will be signing copies of his autobiography
>
> MAGICAL ME” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 4 (At Flourish and Blotts)*</sup></sub>

There can’t be that many additional books than the ones mentioned by name, since his entire bibliography fits in a cauldron.

> “The crowd cheered and clapped and Harry found himself being presented with the entire works of Gilderoy Lockhart. Staggering slightly under their weight, he managed to make his way out of the limelight to the edge of the room, where Ginny was standing next to her new cauldron.
>
> ‘You have these,’ Harry mumbled to her, tipping the books into the cauldron. ‘I’ll buy my own –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 4 (At Flourish and Blotts)*</sup></sub>

There may be a few not mentioned in the books, as it’s possible more than nine books fit in a cauldron, and Harry passed them all off on
Ginny quickly, so we don’t see them. In addition, the writing on Pottermore about Lockhart suggests there might be twelve.

Comment: Magical me is the title for the seven book set. See here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194953/is-magical-me-a-distinct-work-or-is-it-just-the-title-for-gilderoy-lockharts/194954#194954

Comment: @TheAsh In the book, it seems to be a distinctly separate book. In addition to the quote in my answer, it’s also mentioned here: *“When young Harry here stepped into Flourish and Blotts today, he only wanted to buy my autobiography – which I shall be happy to present him now, free of charge –’ the crowd applauded again, ‘– he had no idea,’ Lockhart continued, giving Harry a little shake that made his glasses slip to the end of his nose, ‘that he would shortly be getting much, much more than my book, Magical Me.”  Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 4 (At Flourish and Blotts)*

Comment: In British usage, "Book" can be used to refer to a multivolume book. The end of the paragraph you quote I feel proves that.

Comment: @TheAsh - Book wouldn't usually refer to a multi-volume edition. You'd refer to it as an omnibus or (if novella-length stories) as an anthology. I mean, sure, it's in *book-form*.

Comment: @TheAsh - As much as I hate to toot my own trumpet, I *am* one of the experts who would be deciding :-)

Comment: @Valorum are you an English professor too?

Comment: @TheAsh - Merely an English person with superior verbal and linguistic skills.

Comment: @Valorum But you still don't know that "Book" can be used in the singular for a multivolume series? ;-)

Comment: @Valorum as you guessed, I meant to post this link https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464585/can-book-be-used-in-the-singular-for-a-multi-volume-edition not the scifi link before.

Comment: A multi-volume omnibus would be in book form, but you wouldn't generally call it a book unless you were unaware of its contents.

Comment: @TheAsh - It also seems unlikely that an omnibus edition would contain six or seven other books that are still in print, regardless of the magical ability to make the book larger on the inside. It's just not good business sense....

Comment: @Valorum This is what I'm thinking of https://www.amazon.com/Island-Set-Chapter-Books-Book/dp/B002CC57IY Here it would be "book" even though it is 3 volumes.

Comment: @TheAsh Is that another incorrect link? That's not a single book, and nothing on that page suggests that it is. "Set of 3 Chapter Books", "3 paperbacks". It's a boxset. You keep saying that book can be used in the singular to refer to a multivolume set, but you've provided literally no evidence of that, and the "evidence" you've provided so far contradicts your own point.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist "My favorite book is the encyclopedia". "My favorite book is the lord of the rings" my favorite book is the Bible" even "my favorite book is Harry Poitter" all singular and all multivolume works.

Comment: @TheAsh - LotR is a bad example because it literally is one book.

Answer (score 3):

**We know about 10**
Here is a list of [Gilderoy Lockhart's](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/gilderoy-lockhart) (known) published works.

- [Magical Me](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_Me)
- [Gilderoy Lockhart's Guide to Household Pests](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gilderoy_Lockhart%27s_Guide_to_Household_Pests)
- [Break with a Banshee](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Break_with_a_Banshee)
- [Gadding with Ghouls](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gadding_with_Ghouls)
- [Holidays with Hags](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Holidays_with_Hags)
- [Travels with Trolls](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Travels_with_Trolls)
- [Voyages with Vampires](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Voyages_with_Vampires)
- [Wanderings with Werewolves](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wanderings_with_Werewolves)
- [Year with the Yeti](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Year_with_the_Yeti)
- [Who Am I?](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Who_Am_I%3F)

7 of these 10 Books are all mentioned in Chapter Four of Harry Potter and The Chamber of Secrets on the shopping list for second years.

> “*Break with a Banshee* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>   
> *Gadding with Ghouls* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>   
> *Holidays with Hags* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>   
> *Travels with Trolls* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>   
> *Voyages with Vampires* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>   
> *Wanderings with Werewolves* by Gilderoy Lockhart
>   
> *Year with the Yeti* by Gilderoy Lockhart” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 4 (At Flourish and Blotts)*</sup></sub>

He also wrote his autobiography, Magical Me, which he was selling in Flourish and Blotts.

> “GILDEROY LOCKHART
>   
> will be signing copies of his autobiography
>   
> MAGICAL ME” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 4 (At Flourish and Blotts)*</sup></sub>

About Gilderoy Lockhart's Guide to Household Pests I found this quote in Harry Potter and The Order of the Phoenix:

> Mrs. Weasley was bending over to check the page on doxies in *Gilderoy Lockhart's Guide to Household Pests,* which was lying open on the sofa.
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 6 (The Noble and Most Ancient House of Black)*</sup></sub>

Finally, about Who am I? i found this image.

[image]

This Image is from a Post-Credit scene in Harry Potter and The chamber of Secrets film. [*Chamber of Secrets|Extended clip|Post Credit Scene|HD - Youtube*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_175Mthe9CE)

Note: the sources on the list of books are all wiki-sites, I used them just because they have the list of references from the book/movie. Also, I couldn't find any reference for multiple volumes of Magical Me so I counted it as just one, please comment if I'm wrong.

Comment: here is another reference, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htHK74fug3Q

Comment: ive deleted marauding with monsters for now because i cant find references but i will work on it.

Comment: i do believe it appears in one of the games.... i cant be sure though the sourcing for the references is scant so i will leave it out.

Comment: im pretty sure it was **MENTIONED** in the video-game, seeing as i cant find any proof and the video game is questionable i will leave it out, thanks for pointing this out though!

Comment: theyre are multiple clips on youtube about the post credits scene if you think that one is unreliable: just search up Harry Potter 2 Post-Credits scene.

Comment: I'm not questioning the reliability. I'm questioning whether these books were invented in the movie, as I do not see them mentioned anywhere in the books.

Comment: @Alex i found a quote on Pottermore that mentions Who am I if you want to look at it. https://www.pottermore.com/features/in-defence-of-gilderoy-lockhart

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the repetitive back-and-forth about the canon status of Pottermore has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83311/discussion-on-answer-by-padfoot-how-many-books-did-gilderoy-lockhart-write).