# Is "Magical Me" a distinct work, or is it just the title for Gilderoy Lockhart's multivolume autobiographical works?

Tags: harry-potter

In the comments to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194947/how-many-books-did-gilderoy-lockhart-write/194952#194952), there is a discussion whether Gilderoy Lockhart's "Magical Me" is a distinct work or merely the title of the seven book collection.

Which is correct?

Comment: Can someone ask JKR on Twitter?

Comment: Leave Gilderoy Lockhart alone. The poor guy is still in St. Mungo's..

Comment: We'll let the experts decide https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464585/can-book-be-used-in-the-singular-for-a-multi-volume-edition

Comment: Congrats to 100 questions, Gilderoy! (because who else would ask two Lockhart questions in a row?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### There is potential evidence for both theories, but it seems more likely that *Magical Me* is a separate book

There is a passage that can be taken as evidence of either possibility. At the end of one of the Defense Against the Dark Arts classes Lockhart says:

> "Homework – compose a poem about my defeat of the Wagga Wagga Werewolf! Signed copies of *Magical Me* to the author of the best one!"

Now, if *Magical Me* is just the collection of the other books then all the students already have them. Receiving books they already have would hardly be a good prize. Moreover, Lockhart could have just signed the books they already had rather than giving them new ones that are signed.

On the other hand, if *Magical Me* is a distinct one-volume book, then he should say that the winner will get "**a signed copy**" rather than "**signed copies**".

Of course it is possible that he would give the winner multiple copies of the same book, or that there could be multiple winners. And it's also possible that he would give new signed books rather than signing the books they already have, because a mere signature is not much of a prize – Lockhart had already signed many books for free, and any student could theoretically ask him to sign their books at any time. A prize of actual new books has some physical value, albeit diminished by the fact that it's books they already have.

A passage that supports the theory that *Magical Me* is one book appears when Mrs. Norris is found petrified. Lockhart there says:

> "... I remember something very similar happpening in Ouagadougou," said Lockhart, "a series of attacks, the full story's in my autobiography,

If his autobiography was actually all seven books then he should have said which book it was in (as he does on other occasions).

Additionally when Harry meets Lockhart in Flourish and Blotts we are told:

> The crowd cheered and clapped and Harry found himself being presented with the entire works of Gilderoy Lockhart.

Yet a few moments earlier Lockhart had promised him **his autobiography** for free. As explained in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/194951/100430), there is only one other Lockhart book mentioned in the Harry Potter books (*Gilderoy Lockhart's Guide to Household Pests*). If his autobiography (*Magical Me*) is the whole set of seven books then it is basically itself the entire works of Gilderoy Lockhart. Thus, there wouldn't be such a reason to say that Harry received the entire works. If, however, *Magical Me* is a separate one-volume autobiography then there is a very good reason to say that Harry received the entire works, namely that it is telling us a novel point – that Harry did not only receive the one book Lockhart promised him, but he received **all** of Lockhart's books.

Further potential evidence that *Magical Me* is a separate book comes from the dueling club. There Lockhart says:

> "Now, Professor Dumbledore has granted me permission to start this
>   little dueling club, to train you all in case you ever need to defend
>   yourselves as I myself have done on countless occasions – for full
>   details, see my published works.

If the published works were in fact just the different parts of his autobiography *Magical Me*, he could have just simply said "see *Magical Me*" or "see my autobiography", as he had in fact done on other occasions.

On the other hand, there certainly is biographical material in the set of seven  books required for Hogwarts, such that it might be redundant to have a separate book as his autobiography. Lockhart says, for instance:

> "Tut, tut – hardly any of you remembered that my favorite color is lilac. I say so in *Year with the Yeti* And a few of you need to read *Wanderings with Werewolves* more carefully – I clearly state in chapter twelve that my ideal birthday gift would be harmony between all magic and non-magic peoples – though I wouldn't say no to a large bottle of Ogden's Old Firewhiskey!"

There is other evidence that can perhaps support either theory. Lockhart was signing copies of *Magical Me* in Flourish and Blotts:

> GILDEROY LOCKHART
>
> will be signing copies of his autobiography
>
> *Magical Me*
>
> today 12:30 P.M. to 4:30 P.M.

The Weasleys were waiting on the line to get signed books:

> They each grabbed a copy of *The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 2* and sneaked up the line to where the rest of the Weasleys were standing with Mr. and Mrs. Granger.

If *Magical Me* is in fact the set of books that were on the Hogwarts list it is understandable why the Weasleys are on line. They have to buy the books anyway so they may as well get them signed. But if *Magical Me* is a separate book that is not on the Hogwarts list, it would be strange for the Weasleys to be buying it. After all, they had just complained about not having enough money for Ginny's supplies – why then would they be wasting money on an unnecessary book?

> "That lot won't come cheap," said George, with a quick look at his parents. "Lockhart's books are really expensive...."
>
> "Well, we'll manage," said Mrs. Weasley, but she looked worried. "I expect we'll be able to pick up a lot of Ginny's things secondhand.

On the other hand, if *Magical Me* is simply the set of books needed for Hogwarts and that is what Lockhart was signing, then it is hard to make sense of another passage:

> "You have these." Harry mumbled to her, tipping the books into the cauldron. "I'll buy my own –"

Here Harry gives the books he just got from Lockhart to Ginny, after waiting on the line. Moments later, Ron and Hermione meet him with their own stacks of Lockhart's books:

> Ginny went scarlet as Ron and Hermione fought their way over, both clutching stacks of Lockhart's books.

This implies that they bought the books and got them signed. This would mean that the Weasley's probably already bought books for Ginny, as they were with Harry on line. In that case, Harry's actions are pointless. If, however, *Magical Me* is a separate book then that is the only one that would have been bought. Ginny would still need her Hogwarts books, and then Harry's actions make sense.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. The truth is this might not make sense anyway, because when Mr. Weasley comes over to where Harry and the others are he says:</sup>

> <sup>"What are you doing? It's too crowded in here, let's go outside."</sup>

<sup>If they hadn't bought all the books yet, why would Mr. Weasley suggest leaving the bookstore?</sup>

Comment: Great find with that first quote. Can I add to my answer?

Comment: It strikes me that he'd b giving out multiple copies of a single book (for their friends and families to read)

Comment: @TheAsh I don't own the quotes.

Comment: @Alex The Weasley waiting-in-line proof is great, and IMHO, irrefutable. It clearly shows that JKR's intention was that Magical Me is the set of books, regardless of the singular noun "book" that everyone here is hungup over.

Comment: One can easily imagine that all of Lockhart's books include autobiographical material, but that *Magical Me* is (expressly) his autobiography. And, it's more credible that a number of works that included (some0 non-autobiographical material would be the books assigned for DADA, rather than his autobiography *per se*.

Comment: @RDFozz True. But if he has (allegedly) spent most of his life in Defense Against the Dark Arts exploits then his autobiography would tell all about it and be on-topic for Defense Against the Dark Arts Class. If most of his life is already told in the adventure books, a separate autobiography would not be so necessary. Except to tell us random facts about his life not related to his exploits, e.g. his favorite color. But (at least some of) those things are also covered in the adventure books.

Comment: @Alex - An autobiography could cover things like his childhood, teenage years, etc. - stuff that wouldn't make sense in the more targeted books. And, I suppose I simply see Lockhart as being enough of an egotist to want to pull everything about him into one book - people who might not be interested in Yeti could then still read about the more autobiographical aspects of that time. Of course, much of those "autobiographical details" are almost certainly fictitious, but whay would that stop him?

Comment: @RDFozz I don't disagree with you, hence my equivocal statement in the answer.

Comment: Well reasoned enough that accepted it over my own answer... Congrats, Alex!

Comment: @TheAsh Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## Magical Me seems to be indicated as being a distinct work.

When Lockhart refers to his autobiography, he refers to it as “my book”, which seems to imply that it is likely a distinct work, as book is typically the singular form and usually refers to one book.

> “When young Harry here stepped into Flourish and Blotts today, he only wanted to buy my autobiography – which I shall be happy to present him now, free of charge –’ the crowd applauded again, ‘– he had no idea,’ Lockhart continued, giving Harry a little shake that made his glasses slip to the end of his nose, ‘that he would shortly be getting much, much more than my book, Magical Me.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 4 (At Flourish and Blotts)*</sup></sub>

Also, in the movies, *Magical Me* is shown onscreen as being a distinct book titled *Magical Me*.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

### Magical Me is the title for Gilderoy Lockhart's collected works

including

> Break with a Banshee by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> Gadding with Ghouls by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> Holidays with Hags by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> 43 Travels with Trolls by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> Voyages with Vampires by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> Wanderings with Werewolves by Gilderoy Lockhart
>
> Year with the Yeti by Gilderoy Lockhart

This is clear in Chamber of Secrets:

> “When young Harry here stepped into Flourish and Blotts today, **he only wanted to buy my autobiography — which I shall be happy to present him now, free of charge** —” The crowd applauded again. “He had no idea,” Lockhart continued, giving Harry a little shake that made his glasses slip to the end of his nose, “that he would shortly be getting much, much more than my book, Magical Me. He and his schoolmates will, in fact, be getting the real magical me. Yes, ladies and gentlemen, I have great pleasure and pride in announcing that this September, I will be taking up the post of Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry!” 
>         The crowd cheered and clapped and Harry found himself being presented with the **entire works of Gilderoy Lockhart**.

This is made even clearer later on:

> Staggering slightly under their weight, he managed to make his way out of the limelight to the edge of the room, where Ginny was standing next to her new cauldron.
>   ‘You have these,’ Harry mumbled to her, tipping the books into the cauldron. ‘I’ll buy my own –”

If not all the books are on the school list, why would Harry give them all to Ginny? It seems he was only presented with the complete Lockhart biography, which is exactly what Ginny needs for school. All those books are "Magical Me."

In addition:

> They each grabbed a copy of The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 2 and sneaked up the line to where the rest of the Weasleys were standing with Mr. and Mrs. Granger.

If Magical Me is in fact the set of books that were on the Hogwarts list it is understandable why the Weasleys are on line. They have to buy the books anyway so they may as well get them signed. But if Magical Me is a separate book that is not on the Hogwarts list, it would be strange for the Weasleys to be buying it. After all, they had just complained about not having enough money for Ginny's supplies – why then would they be wasting money on an unnecessary book? (Credit to Alex, above).

In my mind this proof is undeniable.

Additionally, Lockhart himself, in the first Defense Against the Dark arts class appears to describe the books on the Hogwarts list as the complete set:

> "I see you've all bought a complete set of my books – well done."

Also:

> Harry yanked his robes straight and headed for a seat at the very back of the class, where he busied himself with piling **all seven** of Lockhart’s books in front of him.

If Magical Me was a distinct work, there would be eight books, not seven. It certainly wouldn't say "all seven" as if there were no others. So it's clear Magical Me is the title for the seven book set.

In regards to the singular "book", book is often used to described a set of books, if there is a singular title. For example: "My favorite book is Harry Potter." Or "My favorite book is the Bible." Or "My favorite book is the encyclopedia."

I don't care what the wiki says, it's wrong.

Comment: "than my book, Magical Me." Note that it's book singular. Magical Me is a single book.

Comment: There are seven books on the Hogwarts school list, so that doesn't prove that there not separate from *Magical Me*, because Harry would only have the required books in class. Moreover, we anyway know that there are more than seven books becasue there is also *Gilderoy Lockhart's Guide to Household Pests*.

Comment: @Alex Gilderoy Lockhart's Guide to Household Pests is obviously not autobiagrophical and thus would not have been included in the collected works.

Comment: @TheAsh Since when does collected works only include autobiographical material?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Singular here doesn't prove anything. A series can be referred to in English, esp, British English, as a "book.". But Lockhart Clearly says he is presenting him with his Bio and gives him all the books. That implies that all those books are part of Magical Me,

Comment: @TheAsh Or he happened to also give him all the other books too, but not because they were part of the biography.

Comment: @TheAsh A series can only be called a "book" if it's published as a single volume (e.g. some printings of The Lord of the Rings). That's clearly not the case here, as evidenced by your own quote. You've also ignored the fact that Harry gives away the books Lockhart gave to him, and bought his own copies of the ones on the Hogwarts list, so the fact that he later only has seven books doesn't tell us anything useful; he wouldn't care about Lockhart's biography, so wouldn't buy himself a copy for school.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist actually, the giving away proves my point, see edited answer. As for whether a multi-volume book can be called a book, we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: I think you just proved the opposite! Magical Me is just one book, and later Harry has seven books. I read that to mean Harry was given Magical Me AND the other books. Lockhart just mentioned the one he was signing that day.

Comment: @TenthJustice I obviously don't think Magical Me is just one book. I feel it refers to the seven volume set. In British English, Book can be multivolume (Hi, The Bible.)

Comment: @TheAsh I don't think the giving away proves the point. Ginny is more likely to be interested in Lockhart's autobiography than Harry is, so why not dump it on her? She might not need it for school, but it's one less thing for Harry to carry around. You *could* be correct, but I don't think any of the points you've raised are convincing.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I asked it on English.SE https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194953/89771

Comment: @TheAsh You put the wrong link. It should be https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464585/can-book-be-used-in-the-singular-for-a-multi-volume-edition

Comment: @Alex TY for catching that.

Comment: We know there are other Lockhart books, e.g., the guide to household pests, so when he refers to seven books as a "complete set" he can't be being literal.  I can only assume he means "a complete set of those of my works that I could get away with putting on the DADA book list".